# How can i make an interact Slider control the x axis in bar digram to show a part of the data with every change

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipywidgets

How can i make an interact slider control the x axis to show me just 5 bars in a time when i change the value of the slider the chart show me the next five bars and so on
i have tried to do this using interact but it changing the number of the bars
if any body have an idea i will be thankfull
hier the way i tried

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from ipywidgets import interact 
import ipywidgets as ipw

a =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
b =[10,11,10,12,13,11,15,12,20,9,11,12,10,18]
def func(x = 5):
    plt.bar(a[:x],b[:x])
    plt.title('graph 1')
    plt.show()

interact(f,x =ipw.IntSlider(min=1, max=14, step=1,value=10, description='Test:', disabled=False,readout_format='d'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Slider](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider) widget and then set the `valstep` parameter to control how many steps the slider changes every time you click it.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

a =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
b =[10,11,10,12,13,11,15,12,20,9,11,12,10,18,21]

plt.bar(a, b)

bar_number = 5

ax.set_xlim(0.5, bar_number+0.5)

# plt.axes(rect, projection=None, polar=False, **kwargs)
# rect is a 4-tuple of floats  = [left, bottom, width, height]
# A new axes is added with dimensions rect in normalized (0, 1) units using add_axes on the current figure.
# (left, bottom) specify lower left corner coordinates of the new axes in normalized (0, 1) units
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

# Slider(ax, label, valmin, valmax)
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', 0, max(a)-bar_number, valinit=0., valstep=bar_number)

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    ax.set_xlim(pos+0.5, pos+0.5+bar_number)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[plot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg1QU.png)hi thank you a lot for your answer i found onther way using interact ipywidegets

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as ipw

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [2,4,2,4,3,1,5,6,1,9,3]
def f (x):
    plt.bar(a[x:x+3],b[x:x+3] ,color = 'Green')
    plt.title('graph 1')
    plt.show
interact(f,x = ipw.IntSlider(min=a[0], max=a[-3], step=1,value=a[0]))
```